# Why is my flask website only successfully logging one specific user?

Tags: flask, web, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I made a web based music streaming app using flask and sqlite. The problem is that the website is working for one specific user in the database. For others, it is redirecting the website to a different page rather than rendering the home page for the user. This is also happening when I create a new user using the registration page.
Here is the code-

```
@login_manager_user.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__="user"
    user_id=db.Column(db.Integer(),nullable=False,primary_key=True,unique=True)
    username=db.Column(db.String(30),unique=True,nullable=False)
    fname=db.Column(db.String(30),nullable=False)
    lname=db.Column(db.String(30),nullable=False)
    email=db.Column(db.String(50),unique=True,nullable=False)
    password_hash=db.Column(db.String(60),nullable=False)
    song=db.relationship('Songs',secondary='playlist')

    def get_id(self):
        return self.user_id

#creating a route for the sign up page
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register_page():
    form=RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user_to_create=User(username=form.username.data,
                            email=form.email.data,
                            fname=form.f_name.data,
                            lname=form.l_name.data,
                            password_hash=generate_password_hash(form.password1.data))
        db.session.add(user_to_create)
        db.session.commit()
        session['username']=form.username.data
        session['user_id']=user_to_create.user_id
        login_user(user_to_create)
        flash('Account created successfully! Logged in as {}'.format(session['username']),
            category='success')
        return redirect(url_for('user_home', user_name=form.username.data))
    
    if form.errors!={}:
        for err_msg in form.errors.values():
            flash(f'There was an error with creating a user: {err_msg}',category='error')
            return render_template('register.html',form=form)
    
    if request.method=='GET':
        return render_template('register.html',form=form)


#creating a route for login page
@app.route('/login',methods = ['POST','GET'] )
def login_page():
    form=LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        attempted_user=User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if attempted_user and check_password_hash(pwhash=attempted_user.password_hash,
                                                  password=form.password.data):
            session['username']=form.username.data
            session['user_id']=attempted_user.user_id
            creator=Creator.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
            if creator:
                session['creator_id']=creator.creator_id
            login_user(attempted_user)
            flash('Success! You are logged in as: {}'.format(session['username']),category='success')
            return redirect(url_for('user_home',user_name=attempted_user.username))
        else:
            flash('Username and/or password do not match!',category='error')
            return render_template('login.html',form=form)
            

    if request.method=='GET':
        return render_template('login.html',form=form)


#creating a route for the home page of the user
@app.route('/user/<user_name>')
@login_required
def user_home(user_name):
    if request.method=='GET':
        bl_creator=BlackListedCreators.query.filter_by(username=user_name).first()
        if bl_creator: 
            return render_template('blacklist_creator.html')
        songs=Songs.query.all()
        playlists=Playlist.query.filter_by(user=session['user_id']).group_by('playlist_name').all()
        creator=Creator.query.filter_by(username=user_name).first()
        return render_template('home_page.html',user=user_name,
                               creator=creator,songs=songs,playlists=playlists)
```

The weird URL is the last one in the log below-

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Dec/2023 10:25:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Dec/2023 10:25:58] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Dec/2023 10:26:09] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Dec/2023 10:26:09] "GET /user/bhavya HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Dec/2023 10:26:09] "GET /static/js/show_song.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Dec/2023 10:26:12] "GET /logout HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Dec/2023 10:26:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Dec/2023 10:26:17] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Dec/2023 10:26:27] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Dec/2023 10:26:27] "GET /user/yoyohoneysingh HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Dec/2023 10:26:27] "GET /admin?next=/user/yoyohoneysingh HTTP/1.1" 200 
-
```

I don't know how to rectify this.